# Controls en c# y Labels

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

eh tenido un problema al cambiar una secuencia de Labels, el procedimiento para modificar los labels seria el siguiente

```
var controles = Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(x => x.ID.Equals("Labelitem"+i.ToString()  ));
                   foreach (var ctrl in controles)
                   {
                           ctrl.Text = "Hola";
                   }
```

Sin embargo al ejecutarlo ningun control cambia , para que cambien deberia agregar los labels de forma :

```
Controls.add("Labelitem1");

Controls.add("Labelitem2");
```

si los agrego de esa forma , el procedimiento de modificar los labels funciona , sin embargo al ejecutar la pagina desordena toda la estructura de La pagina aspx , mandando al final de la pagina los controles agregados(incluso abajo del footer)

[image: El control agregado se va al fondo de la pagina]

Existe otra forma de agregar los controles sin que desordene el aspx  o obtener los controles de la pagina aspx y asi hacer el ciclo de alteracion de labels?

Comment: Leo, sabes si la variable `controles` contiene los objetos con los que vas a trabajar?

Comment: @Arriel "controles" obtendria los controles de Controls.oftype filtrandolos , obteniendo solo labels , pero en si la propiedad Controls esta vacia